# Is this patent valid? Or just granted and never used

Tags: patentability, pre-grant

In reference to the patent: [US8602429](https://www.google.com/patents/US8602429)

Is this patent Valid? There are a lot of manufactures wordwide who sells exact this product. Can someone check for me if there are any issues going on with this pattent?

Comment: This question may have more to do with licensing than patents.

Comment: Although there may be very similar products, the claims are pretty specific so I'm guessing they aren't "exactly" the same.

Comment: Well, it has some rejected claims, see: http://globaldossier.uspto.gov/svc/doccontent/US/87149710.A/1-7-US%20%20128714970LP1%20/7/PDF

Comment: and dispositiont later... http://globaldossier.uspto.gov/svc/doccontent/US/87149710.A/1-5-US%20%20128714970VP1%20/5/PDF

Answer (score 0):

It is an issued patent. The fees are up to date.  You can check the status yourself on the public [PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site.  If you have evidence that the invention is being practiced in the wild; the cup suspension device may have been licenced, transformed into a company that manufactures the device or simply the patent is being ignored and the owner is not pursuing legal means to protect their patent.